# InApp Purchase productsRequest issue with updating userinterface

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, uilabel

I have a strange problem with updating my user interface with the product information from my InApp purchase product.

I have the following code, to retrieve my product information. My problem is I don't get my labels updated or the "_buyButton" enabled, BUT I see the correct values when I use NSLog. And yes, I linked my IB outlets. In the viewDidLoad method I can change/update my interface objects. I am running the app on real devices.

What is missing?

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSArray *products = response.products;

    if (products.count != 0)
    {
        _product = products[0];
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
        NSLog(@"productsRequest %@", _product.localizedTitle);
    } else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also realized, that I am not able to perform the "buy Action".

```
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
```

It returns the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'
```

Comment: Can I clarify: You get `productsRequest:<some localized title>` in your debug output?

Comment: Yes, I see what I need to see, but a few lines above I am not able to set this value to a UILabel.

Comment: are you the same person as [user3104325](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3104325/user3104325)? This is a very similar question to one asked earlier.

Comment: no I am not, I'm just Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jaydee3 I found the problem, but not a nice solution. The problem was, that the product information were retrieved before the viewcontroller was ready.

I fixed this problem for now, with calling "productsRequest:" from the viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    purchasedApp = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"PurchasedKEY"];


    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    _productID = @"YourIDHere";
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                      [NSSet setWithObject:_productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    }
    else
        _productDescription.text = NSLocalizedString(@"EnableInAppKEY", @"");

    if (!purchasedApp) {
        _buyButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
    _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    NSLog(@"productsRequest %@", _product.localizedTitle);

}
```

Comment: is there any way you can update with more code for your solution, because I'm having the same exact problem!

Comment: Hi, exact same problem for me also. I'm trying to implement your answer. Can you detail what is linked with the key `PurchasedKEY` please ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the values of `_buyButton` or `_productTitle`? Probably they are still nil, when the delegate is called, because the view isn't loaded yet? Am I correct?

When are you starting to load the products? Easiest solution: Load the products from `viewDidLoad:` to make sure, that your view is loaded before.

Comment: Ok just checked it, viewDidLoad gets called before productsRequest. I added NSLog(@"productsRequest %@", _product.localizedTitle); to viewDidLoad but it returns (null).

Comment: put a breakpoint in the delegate method, check the values of `_buyButton` etc. here. If `_product` is nil in `viewDidLoad`, then the delegate hasn't been called before. Than your problem is somewhere else. Show your outlets, show how you alloc/init the viewController.

Comment: I updated my question. The values are nil and I am also not able perform the "buy action". If I understand you correct, the product information is retrieved before the viewcontroller is ready to handle the interface updates?